# proper way to implement a "log out" menu item in react-navigation-drawer?

Tags: react-native

I have a basic implementation of react-navigation-drawer up and running in my RN app.  The drawer displays menu items based on the titles of the configured components. I have a functional "Log Out" button on one of my screens but I need to move the log out functionality to a new "Log Out" menu item in the drawer.

So up to this point, my react-navigation-drawer has displayed menu items based on concrete components.  The new twist is that I need to display an additional "Log Out" menu item which does not have a corresponding screen.  I'm sure that this is a very common use case so I'm just looking for suggestions from other developers who have handled this scenario before?

Comment: If you want a "Log Out", how would you like to "Log In" again without a screen? With a modal?

Comment: if a user is logged out then the app will not find the auth token and will automatically redirect the user to the login screen

Comment: So I guess you have kind of a if else structure to display logged in content or login. After some research I'd suggest to have a look [here](https://codeburst.io/custom-drawer-using-react-navigation-80abbab489f7). I think this is what you are looking for. E.g. custom component to clear auth token.